# How to find the clicked button in the action method

Tags: button, onclick, dialog, dm-script

When I have a dialog and multiple buttons have the same click-callback (action method) I mostly want to know which button has been pressed. How do I do that?

Example:

```c
class ButtonDialog : UIFrame{
    void button_pressed(object self){
        // how do I get this button
        TagGroup pressed_button = ?;
        result("The button " + pressed_button + " is pressed.\n");
    }
    
    object init(object self){
        TagGroup dlg, dlg_items, button1, button2;
        
        dlg = DLGCreateDialog("Press a button", dlg_items);
        
        button1 = DLGCreatePushButton("Button 1", "button_pressed");
        button1.DLGIdentifier("button1");
        dlg_items.DLGAddElement(button1);
        
        button2 = DLGCreatePushButton("Button 2", "button_pressed");
        button2.DLGIdentifier("button2");
        dlg_items.DLGAddElement(button2);
        
        self.super.init(dlg);
        return self;
    }
}

object dialog = alloc(ButtonDialog).init();
dialog.pose();
```

---

In my current program I have multiple rows created from a `TagGroup`. Each row has multiple buttons doing the same thing but for their specific row. Therefore I need to know which button it is to get the row to modify. Also the length of the `TagGroup` and therefore the row count is not fixed. So I cannot create `button1_pressed`, `button2_pressed`, ... functions except with doing some weird stuff with code evaluation on the fly which I want to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you cannot pass an argument in the simple call-back of a push-button is a bit of a bummer. The easiest solution (albeit not elegant) is to use simple-one-line-callback methods which are unique but themselves call a generalized method as in the code below.

Of course *mile7* stated that the number of buttons isn't fixed at compile time, which is an issue here. But unless the (potential) number of buttons is legion, this approach is still the easiest and cleanest, and as each "hard coded" call-back is only one line with a very systemic change, it should be fairly trivial to use Notepad++ or similar to provide an extensive enough set of such calls. (It doesn't hurt if some of them are actually never used.)

```
class ButtonDialog : UIFrame{
    void button_pressed(object self, string buttonID){
        // how do I get this button
        TagGroup pressed_button = self.LookUpElement(buttonID);
        if ( pressed_button.TagGroupIsValid() )
            result("The button " + buttonID + " is pressed.\n");
        else
            result("The button " + buttonID + " was not found!\n");
    }
    
    // Need to be done for each button
    void button_pressed_0(object self) { self.button_pressed("button0"); }
    void button_pressed_1(object self) { self.button_pressed("button1"); }
    
    object init(object self){
        TagGroup dlg, dlg_items
        
        dlg = DLGCreateDialog("Press a button", dlg_items);
        number nButtons = 2
        for( number n=0; n<nButtons; n++ ){
            TagGroup button = DLGCreatePushButton("Button " + n , "button_pressed_" + n);
            button.DLGIdentifier("button" + n);
            dlg_items.DLGAddElement(button);
        }
        
        self.super.init(dlg);
        return self;
    }
}

object dialog = alloc(ButtonDialog).init();
dialog.pose();
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you think it is possible to add the `button_pressed_i()` functions dynamically. Maybe with `ExecuteScriptString()` or somehow inserting the function into the object? As far as I know the callback has to be in the same object and therefore I cannot think of a solution inserting functions to the `UIFrame`.

Comment: @mile7 No, I couldn't think of a dynamic way to do that neither. Not saying it is absolutely impossible, though. But honestly, I think it is a bit of overkill and academic. While *nice*, the purpose of most scripts is to *do* something, and if I have, say 100lines of "static" code in there, why bother?

Answer (score 0):

So I kind of found an answer which I can live with, but I'm still hoping for better results.

My current idea is to use DualStateBevelButtons. If a button gets clicked, the state changes and the callback is executed. Then all buttons are checked if they have a changed state. If so, this is the clicked button and the state is reset.

The very very big downside of this solution is, that there are only buttons with images allowed, no text is possible. So this is not really the general solution to work with.

```c
rgbimage button_img = RGBImage("button-image", 4, 16, 16);
button_img = max(0, 255 - iradius / 8 * 255);

class ButtonDialog : UIFrame{
    TagGroup buttons;
    
    void button_pressed(object self){
        for(number i = 0; i < buttons.TagGroupCountTags(); i++){
            TagGroup button;
            if(buttons.TagGroupGetIndexedTagAsTagGroup(i, button)){
                if(button.DLGGetValue() == 1){
                    // this button is toggled so it is clicked
                    string identifier;
                    button.DLGGetIdentifier(identifier);
                    
                    result("Button " + i + " (" + identifier + ") is clicked.\n");
                    
                    // reset button state
                    button.DLGBevelButtonOn(0);
                    
                    // do not continue searching, found pressed button already
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    object init(object self){
        TagGroup dlg, dlg_items, button1, button2;
        
        dlg = DLGCreateDialog("Press a button", dlg_items);
        buttons = NewTagList();
        
        button1 = DLGCreateDualStateBevelButton("button1", button_img, button_img, "button_pressed");
        buttons.TagGroupInsertTagAsTagGroup(infinity(), button1);
        dlg_items.DLGAddElement(button1);
        
        button2 = DLGCreateDualStateBevelButton("button2", button_img, button_img, "button_pressed");
        buttons.TagGroupInsertTagAsTagGroup(infinity(), button2);
        dlg_items.DLGAddElement(button2);
        
        self.super.init(dlg);
        return self;
    }
}

object dialog = alloc(ButtonDialog).init();
dialog.pose();
```